# How to check for Objective 2.0 support by GCC under linux?

Tags: objective-c, linux, gcc, clang

I'm under linux and I have both `clang 3.5`, from the svn trunk, and `gcc 4.8.1`. It surprises me that I can't compile `objective-c 2.0` code with `gcc` but I can do that with `clang`.

I know that `gcc` was the default compiler on `MAC OS X` for a long time before the coming of `clang`. So why `gcc` doesn't support `obj-c 2.0` under linux?

`clang` even works fine with GNUstep, where `gcc` really can't keep up in terms of implemented features from the version 2.0 of the language.

For example, the `autoreleasepool` keyword it's not supported by `gcc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on what you mean by “Objective-C 2.0”.  There's no official written specification.

Several language features that you probably think of as “Objective-C 2.0” are only supported by clang and have never been supported by gcc.  These include ARC, `NSNumber`/`NSArray`/`NSDictionary` literals, and object subscripting.  The `@autoreleasepool` syntax is part of ARC.

Comment: Apple realeased a pdf document in the 2009 about programming with objc-2.0. The tag used in my post confirms that . I'm still not into the language specs, but clearly there is an objectiveC language labeled `2.0` by Apple itself. So, there are even no forks or branches from `gcc` with a good `objc-2.0` implementations ? `clang` is the only compiler in the world that provides `objc-2.0` ?

Comment: Please post a link to the PDF.  As far as I know, Apple used “Objective-C 2.0” informally to mean the collection of new language features they released in 2006.  There's no standards body for Objective-C and no written specification that I've seen (especially since Apple took down the outdated *The Objective-C Programming Language* book).  In 2006, Apple implemented the new features in gcc.  Since then they have abandoned gcc and implemented several new language features in clang.  There's no official name or version number for the language apart from the compiler version.

Comment: You can find some information about which compiler version support which language features in Apple's [Objective-C Feature Availability Index](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/index.html), but you'll notice that older features like `@property` and instance-variables-in-`@implementation`, which are supported by both gcc and clang, aren't even listed.

Comment: Here you go http://cagt.bu.edu/w/images/b/b6/Objective-C_Programming_Language.pdf , thanks for that link, I wasn't expecting `objc` to be so restricted in terms of support, even on `MAC` `gcc` is still quite popular.

Comment: out of curiosity what is the pdf that you mentioned ?

Comment: to be clear: I accepted your answer but I'm still interested in those pdfs, if you can possibly provide links to them it will be a nice thing to have as a reference .

Comment: I don't have any PDFs. You mentioned a PDF and I asked for a link.

Comment: ok, but you can't reach the resources you mentioned on the official Apple developer website ? Just to have a precise reference.

Comment: I don't understand what resources you are asking for.